# Empty test suite with PolIdeaTestRunner

Tags: android, unit-testing

i am doing unit test for my code. even though i am having the test suite, it will say as "Empty test Suite" with Pol idea test runner.

Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Test running failed: Unable to find instrumentation info for: ComponentInfo{com.example/pl.polidea.instrumentation.PolideaInstrumentationTestRunner}
Empty test suite.

Answer (score 1):

After long time found answer my self:

we have to specify the testInstrumentationRunner in defaultConfig in build.gradle file

```
defaultConfig {
    testInstrumentationRunner "pl.polidea.instrumentation.PolideaInstrumentationTestRunner"
}
```